# Counting in sas

Tags: sas

Maybe a stupid question...
I got following dataset:

```
id count
x    1  
y    2
z    3
a    1
b    2
c    3
etc.
```

And  i want this:

```
id count group
x    1    1
y    2    1
z    3    1
a    1    2
b    2    2
c    3    2  
etc.
```

Here is what I try:

```
data macro_1; set vix.macro_spy; where macro=1;
count+1;
if count>3 then do;
    count=1;
end;
    group=0;
    if count=1 then group+1;
    run;
```

But it is not working. How can I add all 'group' by one if I once get a 'count=1'?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

even simpler

```
data want;
set vix.macro_spy;
group+(count=1);
run;
```

Comment: It's evaluating count=1 as true/false, which in SAS take the values 1/0.  Therefore when count=1 it adds 1 to the group value, otherwise it adds 0. 
When creating a variable in the form var+..., the previous value is retained automatically.  If you put var=var+... then you need to specify an explicit retain statement.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a personal preference but I always like to use the `eq` operator instead of `=` when I'm doing a comparison just so that it's clear that I'm not doing an assignment.  Just helps my brain read the code more easily but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you need. So you have this dataset ordered so that values of variable `count` always go `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3...`
Now, you want to generate variable `group` so that value increments every time variable `count` passes over 3?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
data group;
  set vix.macro_spy;
  retain group;
  if _N_ = 1 then group = 0;
  if count = 1 then group + 1;
run;
```

This is the general pattern that I'm using.
`if _N_ = 1` part is executed only once, this is where you initialize you variables.

`retain` statement ensures that the variable will retain its value from one iteration of the DATA step to the next.